# RetentionPolicy of RUNTIME in old JRE?

Tags: java, annotations, runtime, retention

What will happen when a Class or Interface who is annotated with an annotation of `RetentionPolicy#RUNTIME` is loaded in old JREs?

```java
@FunctionalInterface // Java8 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public interface MyFunctional {
}
```

Is above interface or any class implement that interface can run in JRE 7 or older?

Comment: What happens when you try? Why would you run code dependant on Java 8 classes and features on Java 7?

Comment: @JBNizet I exactly expected the kind of your comment. Who possibly has multiple JRE installed machine? I know I would have been done myself if I have old JRE7 remained on my machine even after I installed JRE8

Comment: I have (at least) 3 different JDK installations on my machine. And I guess almost all Java developers have multiple JDKs installed because some projects use Java 6, some others Java 7, and some others Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are handled slightly different than other *normal* classes. If the JVM cannot load the annotation class for a runtime annotation, this annotation will be dropped and you cannot find hints anymore that there was an annotation.